# Concatenar listas de um único vetor

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, matemática, física

O que vou perguntar eu sei fazer em C, mas de um modo bastante ingênuo. Agora, estou aprendendo Python.

A minha pergunta é:
Eu tenho um sistema dinâmico a tempo discreto, como por exemplo: Pn = P + F. Eu acabei criando vetores a partir do Numpy, usando:
`import numpy as np`. Neste caso, eu uso um loop para iterar o mapa:

```
for i in range(iteradas):
    P[i+1] = P[i] + F[i]
```

Até aí tudo bem. O vetor F é gerado a partir de uma distribuição normal: `F = np.random.normal(media, variancia, iteradas)`.

O problema é que agora eu quero usar o pacote *statistics* para calcular a variância da sequência de P's, mas não a sequência temporal, mas nas condições iniciais.

Eu quero implementar o código para mais condições iniciais, de modo que eu tenha um loop dentro do loop, assim:

```
for cond in range(10):
    for i in range(iteradas):
        P[i+1] = P[i] + F[i]
```

Aqui, *cond* se refere às 10 condições iniciais. Eu sei que isto funciona, pois eu ploto as trajetórias geradas e elas são como esperado. Contudo, eu não faço ideia de como somar termo a termo correspondente de cada condição inicial. Em outras palavras, eu quero fazer a média sobre as condições iniciais (realizações), e não sobre o tempo.

Por exemplo, P[1] da primeira condição inicial é associado com P[1] da segunda, P[1] da terceira, e assim sucessivamente para todos.

Em C eu faria um vetor nas condições iniciais, mas considerando que o Python oferece o pacote statistics, eu queria aproveitar a função existente.

Eu já tentei o `zip` mas não consegui concatenar as coisas.

--
EDIT

Aqui está um trecho do código:

```
for cond in range(condicoes):
    X[0] = 0
    P[0] = 0
    F = np.random.normal(media, variancia, iteradas)
    for l in range(iteradas):
        P[l + 1] = P[l] + F[l]
    print(P)
    v.append(P)
```

O que acho mais estranho é que ao rodar `print(P)`, eu tenho uma lista por condição, como sugeriu Woss. Contudo, ao usar `print(v)`, saem todas as listas repetidas, impossibilitando fazer qualquer estatística sobre a nova lista.

Comment: Pela descrição, parece que o `zip` funcionaria perfeitamente, desde que cada condição gere uma lista separada. Como que tentou utilizar?

Comment: Woss, eu consigo fazer isto manualmente: ```[sum(x) for x in zip(a,b)]``` para duas listas, mas não consigo pensar em como gerar a sequência de P's pela lei de formação e salvar em várias listas para várias condições iniciais para então usar o comando acima.

Comment: Eu defino  ```v=[]```. Assim, ao usar v.append(P), eu esperava obter uma lista feita com as várias listas de P (uma lista de P para cada condição inicial). Contudo, ```print(v)``` retorna uma lista feita de várias listas iguais.

Comment: Provavelmente porque você só está sobrescrevendo P a cada nova lista. O ideal é que você recrie essa lista a cada iteração do laço.

Comment: Consegui. Obrigado, Woss. Era isto mesmo. Agora eu só não sei como "zipar" as listas. Obtive: v = [[1,2,3], [3,2,5], [4,5,6]], para três condições iniciais e três iteradas. Agora preciso zipar (1,3,4), (2,2,5), (3,5,6) e usar statistics. Como faço para zipar desse jeito?

Comment: Logo como zip(*v)

Comment: Muito bom. Obrigado!